# missing entry in launchctl after restart

Tags: macos, daemon

I have a deamon which is registered with *launchctl* to run as system-wide-daemon and to load automatically with every system startup or if the daemon crashes.

I have registered this daemon with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/plist.file
```

Everything works fine. My daemon is registered and with

```
sudo launchctl list
```

I can find the entry at *launchctl*

But on some Macs after the user restarts the system, my daemon is not running. And with the command `sudo launchctl list` I can't find the entry anymore.

Any ideas, why the entry is missing???

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `-w`, then the `Disabled` key is probably set.

Comment: I think, that the problem is not the -w parameter, because the whole entry gets lost. After installation everything works fine, 'sudo launchctl list' displays me my registered daemon. But after a system restart i can not find this entry at 'sudo launchctl list'.
Maybe you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

User launch daemons should be stored in `~/library/launchagents` or `/library/launchagents` or `/library/launchdaemons` (to run whenever the system boots but before anybody logs)